# Is it possible to add descriptions for the yas-choose-value choices?

Tags: yasnippet

I got a simple snippet for the opening a file in PHP:

```
fopen('${1:./filename.txt}', '${2:$$(yas-choose-value '("r" "w" "a" "x" "r+" "w+" "a+" "x+"))}') or die();
```

So when I get to the choose the file opening mode, r,w,a,x... I get the dropdown:

```
r
w
a
.
```

But I would like to add a description of whats the function of each mode, like:

```
r   - Open read only
w   - Open for write erases content
.
.
```

Is it possible to do this with `yas-choose-value`?

Comment: Users are not restricted to `yas-choose-value` or `yas-completing-read`.  There are a handful of built-in functions, but you (or another forum participant) is free to write a custom function.  It looks like this:  `(unless (or yas-moving-away-p yas-modified-p) ...)` with the `...` needing to be replaced with the custom Lisp that does whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using an alist of choices, with the `car` being the choice`+`description and the `cdr` being the actual choice.  There are a variety of options that `yasnippet` offers for user input (see `yas-prompt-functions` with a default value of `yas-dropdown-prompt`, `yas-completing-prompt`, `yas-maybe-ido-prompt`, and `yas-no-prompt`), some of which may not support an alist of choices.  As indicated in a comment above, the user is not confined to either `yas-choose-value` or `yas-completing-read`.  The key ingredient is `(unless (or yas-moving-away-p yas-modified-p) ...)` with the `...` needing to be replaced with the custom Lisp that does whatever you want.  Here is a custom example that uses `ido`:

```lisp
fopen('${1:./filename.txt}', '${2:$$(unless (or yas-moving-away-p yas-modified-p)
  (require 'ido)
  (let* ((choices-alist '(("r - Open read only" . "r")
                          ("w - Open for write erases content" . "w")
                          ("a - The 'a' description." . "a")
                          ("x - The 'x' description." . "x")
                          ("r+ - The 'r+' description." . "r+")
                          ("w+ - The 'w+' description." . "w+")
                          ("a+ - The 'a+' description." . "a+")
                          ("x+ - The 'x+' description." . "x+")))
         (choice (ido-completing-read "Please choose one:  " choices-alist nil 'confirm)))
    (cdr (assoc choice choices-alist))))}') or die();
```

---

The following ticket requests that the Emacs team implement support for ido tab completion using an alist collection, and I have provided a draft proof concept for said implementation:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=46091